# Add bootstrap in Quasar project

Tags: bootstrap-5, quasar-framework

I added bootstrap in a quasar v3 project and import it css min at quasar.config.js file.

```
css: [
      '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      'app.scss'
    ],
```

When I open devtools at navigator, I see the follow warning message: 'DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:9000/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE'

I saw in bootstrap.min.css this line `/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */`
If I remove this line, the warning message disapear, but I think I shouldn't edit this file.

I added sourceMapping in quasar.config.js file, but the console show the same warning message

```
build: {
      target: {
        browser: [ 'es2019', 'edge88', 'firefox78', 'chrome87', 'safari13.1' ],
        node: 'node16'
      },

      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      sourceMappingURL: '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map'
}
```

How I can remove the warning error?